# Confused about GCM Token updation process

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Trying to implement google's latest `GCM` services. I have read [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). I have also downloaded & analysed [google's sample implementation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start). From all the above I understood the following:

1. `InstanceId` services provide APIs to generate `gcm registration tokens` You send & store this generated token in your app server.
2. These tokens can be changed once in a while from client side as well as instanceId service side as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#keeping-the-registration-state-in-sync). To handle this, you have to implement `InstanceIDListenerService` and the InstanceID provider will call  `onTokenRefresh` where you just write your logic to get a new token and sending it to server ([Google's sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyInstanceIDListenerService.java) )
3. There's something called `canonical_id` ([as mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids)) (which is the last registration_id send from a device) that GCM server sends your device if your app server sends an older registration id. You have to replace your existing token in server with this canonical_id.

Now, following are my questions:

1. `InstanceId.getToken` seems to return same token if the app is not uninstalled and it returns pretty fast if the token hasn't changed. So, can I call the `RegistrationIntentService` every time I start the app? This way I'm guaranteed to get to work with the latest token all the time.
2. How does the `onTokenRefresh` if refresh happens while your app is not  connected to the play store (no internet or something)? Does `InstanceId` provider re-try? Is this documented somewhere? What happens if at the same time a push notification is sent?
3. What exactly is a `canonical_id`? is it the latest token generated for a device (initiated by `InstanceID.getToken` at client or at `InstanceId` provider end)? If `canonical_id` is indeed the latest gcm token, what is the need of `onTokenRefresh` implementation as you can anyway analyse the push notification data and update your app server if you find a `canonical_id` provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I call the RegistrationIntentService every time I start the app?

A better solution would be to save in preference that you already managed to register a token. start `RegistrationIntentService` only if you didn't already register.

```
String token = InstanceID.getToken(...);
//send to server
getSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean(PREFIX_PREF_GCM_KEY, true).apply();
```

then when you start your app just check if `PREFIX_PREF_GCM_KEY` is true

> How does the onTokenRefresh if refresh happens while your app is not connected to the play store (no internet or something)

I'm guessing that it's up to the system to call this `refresh procedure`. the documentation states:

> Called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed. The application should call getToken() and send the tokens to all application servers.
>   This will not be called very frequently, it is needed for key rotation and to handle special cases.
>   The system will throttle the refresh event across all devices to avoid overloading application servers with token updates.

It can be called while your app is asleep (same as when you are getting notification) but you should test it and see that it's working as expected.

I also think that you can assume that while there is no internet connection, the `System` will not call `onRefreshToken` for the simple reason that it won't be able to receive update notifications... but as always you should test by yourself to see if the update process works and in which conditions.

> What exactly is a canonical_id?

It's possible that by mistake you have registered multiple registration id's for the same device in **your** server - for example - `onRefreshToken` - registered a token without deleting the old one.
If you will send a message using the old `registartaion_id`, google will let you know you should change it to the new one - the *canonical_id*

Comment: thanks! I understand that you can keep within `sharedpreferences` as I have been doing this for my older GCM API (`GCM.register`). However, now I'm confused with this token updation. My basic question is whether canonical_id sent is same as the latest token of that device. Because if that is the case, there may not be a need for the onRefreshToken implementation altogether.

Comment: Why not? It's a process that enables you solve issues before they arises (updating the token before using the old one).

Comment: As per the docs, if you find a `registration_id` in the gcm response, it means registration token that you have in app server is outdated and it should be replaced with the one in `registration_id`. My issue is that, (1) `InstanceID service` decides to refresh token and calls your implementation of  `onRefreshToken` and there you would have anyway called `InstanceID.getToken` and updated server database in it. Once updation is done, your app server will be having latest tokens. From then on, I cannot find a case where you would find `registration_id` in the gcm response. (cont.d)

Comment: In case that you couldn't update in your server the new refresh token, in case where you have inserted this new refreshed token but didn't delete the old one. in short in case of an error

Comment: The only possible case would be if a push notification happening between your latest token registration and the updation of the same in the server. I guess my original problem was that I assumed that somehow google could update your token from their end. That was why I was asking the need for `onRefreshToken`.

Comment: `The only possible case` - that is not true, read my post and comments and google docs, It's up to YOU to update your server with a new registration_id so there could be many possibilities for why you have both registration_id and canonical_id

Comment: I was assuming doing everything right so I couldn't think of much error scenarios :) btw, I have another related question that I have asked here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167533/how-to-initiate-an-android-gcm-token-refresh You are welcome to help. Thanks, again!

Comment: "I was assuming doing everything right" - lol (-; and please don't forget to accept the answer if it seems correct to you, or vote it up, thanks