# How to initiate an android GCM token refresh?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As per the the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#how-uninstalled-client-app-unregistration-works),

> To protect the client app and app server from potential malicious
>   re-use of registration tokens, you should periodically initiate token
>   refresh from the server. When GCM registration token refresh is
>   initiated from server side, the client app must handle a
>   tokenRefreshed message with the GCM registration client/server
>   handshake.

Are the steps to initiate gcm registration token refresh documented somewhere?

I know about `InstanceIDListenerService` and `onTokenRefresh`. Those are for creating a new token and updating it to your app server. But how to do specifically the  following bit?

> periodically initiate token refresh from the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to schedule a job on the server that sends a notification with `ACTION` `REFRESH_TOKEN` every few months (GCM recommends 6 months). On the client apps, on your message callback, `switch` on the `ACTION` and handle the refresh token.

---

**Old answer**

Have you seen this page: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#refresh_tokens

> The Instance ID service initiates callbacks periodically (for example,
>   every 6 months), requesting that your app refreshes its tokens. It may
>   also initiate callbacks when:
>
> - There are security issues; for example, SSL or platform issues.
> - Device information is no longer valid; for example, backup and restore.
> - The Instance ID service is otherwise affected.

Comment: Yes, I have read that. I know that instance ID service can initiate token refresh process. My question how *you* can initiate token refresh from *your* server as they mentioned that it is advised that you should do so.

Comment: How do you exactly "handle refresh token"? Because I tried calling `instanceID.getToken` when I receive notification with `ACTION` `REFRESH_TOKEN`, it returns the same token.