# Refreshing GCM token

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to issue a new GCM token for my android app. I implemented the InstanceIDListenerService interface to handle such an event..

The question is how do I actually initiate a refresh token so the onTokenRefresh() will be called, and instanceID.getToken will return a new registered token?

Comment: did you look here? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#public-methods

Comment: @tyczj , yes.. They do talk about deleting tokens, but I can't find a way to refresh the token, so onTokenRefresh will be called.

Comment: onTokenRefresh only gets called when the token expires. if you delete it manually it does not get called. when deleting it manually all you have to do is call getToken again and you get a new token. you cannot manually invoke onTokenRefresh

Comment: @tyczj http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167533/how-to-initiate-an-android-gcm-token-refresh - so the posted answer was referring to delete/getToken on the client app?

Comment: yes, the answer is saying to send a GCM push to your app to start that process yourself

Answer (score 0):

As long as `onTokenRefresh` is not called by GCM it means that your token is still valid. You don't have to trigger a refresh on your own.